# Update JSON element from ngModel then http POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ngmodel

Okay, I'm fairly new to Angular, but I got stuck and it's probably a rather simple solution.

I have a very basic Angular App with a "Page View/Controller" and a "Admin View/Controller" that use the same JSON files to populate data.

Obviously I want to CRUD some elements in the Admin View, and by this I mean, modify my JSON file.

Heres a piece of my JSON file

```
  {
  "id": 22,
  "title": "",
  "section": "expositions",
  "text": "2005 : « Ce soir la lune reve » (Casa de Francia et IFAL - Mexico DF)",
  "url": "",
  "fr": "",
  "es": "",
  "en": "",
  "active": false
  },
  {
  "id": 23,
  "title": "",
  "section": "expositions",
  "text": "2006 : « Ce monde rayonnant » (Espace Triangle - Bruxelles, Belgique)",
  "url": "",
  "fr": "",
  "es": "",
  "en": "",
  "active": false
  }
```

I got all these elements in my controller's scope

```
$http.get('http://example.com/js/texts.json').then(function (result){
   $scope.texts = result.data;
});
```

Everything works fine and I'm able to populate my view with ngModel.

```
<ul class="angular-content">
   <li ng-repeat="expo in texts | filter:{section: 'expositions'}">
    <h4>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="expo.active">
      <textarea rows="2" cols="124" ng-model="expo.text"></textarea>
    </h4>
    <h4 ng-show="expo.fr"><a target="_blank" href="{{expo.fr}}">FR</a></h4>
    <h4 ng-show="expo.es"><a target="_blank" href="{{expo.es}}">ESP</a></h4>
    <h4 ng-show="expo.en"><a target="_blank" href="{{expo.en}}">ANG</a></h4>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Where I'm stuck is when I modify the values of those `<textarea>`s and try to update my JSON file.

```
$scope.saveTexts = function () {
$scope.newTexts = JSON.stringify($scope.texts);
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://example.com/js/text.json',
  data: $scope.newTexts,
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

}

I'm guessing it's a problem of asynchronous calls or the way I'm using JSON.stringify When I console log, my changes won't appear still.

---

It also doesn't work properly when I try to add an element:

If I use this function in a ng-click, my view will update and add such element, but not in my $scope.texts

```
$scope.addExpo = function(){
$scope.texts.push({
  "id": 35,
  "title": "TEST",
  "section": "expositions",
  "text": "TEST",
  "url": "TEST  ",
  "fr": "",
  "es": "",
  "en": "",
  "active": true
});
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: You can't save directly into a file using `$http`.  You would need a server that can receive the `POST` content with access to the underlying file system.

Comment: Do you have control over the backend server? If so what are you using?

Comment: You can't POST to a json file either. It has to be done using a server side programming language or use a third party storage service for your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't save data directly to JSON-file via $http-request.
Here is my advice:

- use server side script(PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.) that will handle requests from Angular
- use ngResource - it's good for CRUD operations

Comment: Well I didn't thought about that. I will implement it as soon as I can. Probably going to use Python. Will post my answer.